# selective call to write wrapper

Tags: c, linux, wrapper

I have intercepted the write library function to redirect writes but want only a few writes to uae the wrapper whereas others(used for writing to sockets) should go to the original libc function. Have tried using dlsym but does no seem to work.

have used the LD-PRELOAD environment variable

Would appreciate help

An Edit:
A portion of the code

```
int call_execute()
{
.....
    static ssize_t (*real_write)(int,const void*,size_t) = NULL;
...

    real_write= (size_t(*)(int,const void*,size_t)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"write");

...
    real_write(sockfd,argcalls[i],strlen(argcalls[i]));

}
```

Comment: Could you add some code to your question? especially the bits around the `dlsym` usage`

Comment: What are you trying to do and why? The info you posted is not sufficient to answer the question.

Comment: My main issue is dlsym-ing does not seem to work...call to write (real_write here) goes through the write wrapper i have written and preloaded ..

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

typedef ssize_t (*readf)(int, void *, size_t);

ssize_t
read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count) {
    readf p = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "read");
    printf("passing read with %d bytes\n", count);
    return p(fd, buf, count);
}
```

$gcc -W -Wall -shared -o /tmp/libpre.so test.c -ldl

$env LD_PRELOAD=/tmp/libpre.so cat /dev/null

Above should produce output like this:

passing read with 32768 bytes

Answer (score 0):

If `dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "write")` doesn't return the libc function, you can explicitly state the library you want, e. g.

```
void *handle = dlopen("libc.so.6", RTLD_LAZY);
if (!handle) puts(dlerror()), exit(1);
typeof(&write) real_write = dlsym(handle, "write");
```

- but easier perhaps it would be if you didn't use LD_PRELOAD in the first place and defined your write wrapper in the main program - then RTLD_NEXT should work.